# In Google DFP, "Out of Page" not showing up on the trafficked page

Tags: ads, google-dfp, interstitial

We are migrating our ad infrastructure from using adtech to DFP. We are facing a particular roadblock regarding any ads which are of the type out of page. We have pre-stitial and wallpaper/skin ads of the type out-of-page. Both face same issue.

I can see that the markup+scripts for that ad are correctly being called & inserted in the DOM right inside the oop div container we had setup. The problem seems that the iframe tag generated by GPT is setting the height & width of the iframe (which contains the markup+scripts of the ad) to 1 px each. Not only this, it is not respecting the OOP nature of the ad, since it is not setting the position to absolute & top, left as 0 in the CSS. It is **not performing the busting of the iframe** so to speak.

To give you bit of a context we have made sure of following things,

- Initializing the GPT like so, `var prestitialOOP = googletag.defineOutOfPageSlot('/1234567890/Core/ROS/Prestitial', 'div-gpt-ad-1397599585565-0-oop');`
  `prestitialOOP.addService(googletag.pubads());`
- Making sure that the creative `Test_Prestitial` is marked as `Out-of-page`
- Making sure that none of the code+css in our side does not interfere with google generated markup.

[P.S. this is the link to the creative template code we are using.](https://code.stypi.com/tankchintan/oop.html)

Please let us know how we can debug this situation better. Also if anyone can show us a site and template where its working so we can learn from there.

FYI, when I manually set the css of the injected `iframe` to take over the complete viewscreen then the ad shows up fine.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue? I'm having a similar issue with DFP's 1px iframe width/height hiding the ad.

Comment: @ndmweb I didnt find any direct solution, so I created my own. I will add to the asnwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to programatically set the width/height of the ad container. I am posting below the complete solution for doing DFP out-of-page ads like prestitial.

[Markup Shell](https://gist.github.com/tankchintan/3387b320779538b61805)

[JavaScript code to render the presttial ad](https://gist.github.com/tankchintan/50279bbbba3c179fd919)

[Style in LESS](https://gist.github.com/tankchintan/2dfc3170ab6337b340e7)